# Changes not reflecting in java class files even after redeploying WAR file ? Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

I changed some coding of java source file in my web app and exported to WAR arhive from Eclipse. Then I undeployed old webapp and redeployed the new one on Tomcat 7.0.27.

The changes not updated. I displayes Only the old codeing's output.

What can I do ?

I reloaded the APP , restarted Tomcat ,restarted whole system , re-exprorted and redeployed ..  but no result.

Even the source .java file in web-inf/classes folder is updated to the new code , but the web app output still giving old output.

So I click "Find leaks" option in Tomcat Manager app , it shows following message :

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed),
>   but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus
>   causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm): /patent2

I think the class file not updated.

How can I rectify it . ?

Comment: I think this is that kind of problem when you miss something simple after a long hard day. BTW, did you clean project and do you have "Build automatically" checkbox under "Project" menu enabled?

Comment: @alsid .. Yes. I enabled Build automatically